# How to insert not matching existing row and also Update non Existing row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have two Table `T1` and `T2` of identical structure is as follows, `ID` and `Filename` Combination identifies a `Unique ROW` in both table

```
       T1                                         T2
ID  FileName  IsActive             ID   FileName  IsActive
```

Now I want to write two different queries in two different scenario

Scenario 1

```
Row exist T1 but not in T2  
in this scenario insert the rows which exist in T1 but not in T2
```

Scenario 2

```
ROW Doest not exist in T1 but exist in T2 
in this scenario update T2 set IsActive of that rows as 0
```

`ID` and `Filename` Combination identifies a `Unique ROW` in both table

Any help in writing the query?

Comment: You need [merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

Comment: Refer to the URL, https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 0):

**First query:**

```
INSERT INTO T2 (ID, FileName, IsActive)
SELECT T1.ID, T1.FileName, T1.IsActive
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2
     ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.FileName = T2.FileName
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

**Second query:**

```
UPDATE T2
SET T2.IsActive = 0
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1
     ON T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2.FileName = T1.FileName
WHERE T1.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: @rajibdey No, the second should be `INSERT`.  In both cases, the records which do not match during the join in one table should be inserted into the other table.

Comment: in Second Scenario my requirement is to Update T2 and set IsActive =0 when T1 Doesnot have row but T2 has ROW

Comment: thats ok..I am trying that and will test if that works by the way can I alias the table if yes how becoze in relatity table name is long